# Django field not appearing in validated data but it's in request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have these serializers:

```py
class OneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OneModel
        fields = ['time_column', 'event_column']


class TwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    survival_columns = OneSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserFile
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'survival_columns']
```

Now in the `create` method I'm trying to retrieve `survival_columns` values from `validated_data` but **it's not present!** If I print the POST data the field and values appear correctly:

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
   print(self.context['request'].POST)  # <QueryDict: {'name': ['Clinical data.csv'], 'survival_columns': ['{"event_column":"Test","time_column":"Test"}']}>
   print(validated_data)  #  {'name': 'Clinical data.csv'}
```

Why is the field `survival_columns` being filtered from the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making the request with FormData and the `survival_columns` field was an array which was Stringyfied before being sent. This combination of FormData and JSON is nos supported by Django REST Framework as [this article](https://medium.com/@ahm3d.hisham/drf-nested-params-and-multipart-488c86d89191) pointed out.

The solution was manually decode the field using `json` built-in package:

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
    ...
    survival_columns_str = self.context['request'].POST.get('survival_columns', '[]')
    survival_columns = json.loads(survival_columns_str)
    ...
```